# jQuery AJAX not working in Safari browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, safari

I have this simple code to load data via AJAX. On other browsers it works fine, but on Safari it simply does not work. It says:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500

```js
$.ajax({
  url: WEB_URL + 'folder/submit.php',
  method: 'POST',
  data: {
    member: JSON.stringify({
      avatar: 'value'
    })
  },
  success: function(response) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      try {
        let data = JSON.parse(response);
        // random code
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
      }
    }, TIME_SLOW);
  },
  error: function(error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
});
```

Can someone help?

Comment: Does it work in any browser?

Comment: The error means that the issue is on the server, not your JS. However it's possible that Safari is not serialising the data in the same way. Check devtools to ensure that all browsers send the same data in the body of the request. I would also suggest you serialise the entire body content, not just the `member` property.

Comment: why to serialize? can I not send just a json?

Comment: Know that an error in PHP with ajax can cause a 500 too. Should not need to use `stringify`, try passing data as `data: {member:{avatar:'value'}},`. Can also use `error_log` in the PHP side to see what is being passed through. Somewhere in the PHP file should echo `json_encode` on whatever data is being returned for the response.